# Is there a command to open a new terminal from the terminal command line in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: command-line

I have many bash files to run when I sit down for a programming session.

I was hoping that there was an actual command to open a new terminal from the terminal command line. Not looking to do this via  keyboard shortcuts.

My desire is to :

1. Open a terminal from my Mac
2. Logon to my Ubuntu 18.04 server
3. Run one bash command that runs several bash files in their own new terminals

Comment: You may want to look at the command `screen`. Type `man screen` in an Ubuntu terminal.

Comment: Or `tmux`, if you're feeling adventurous..

Answer (score 0):

Have a go and type:
`$ man bash` and as you have launched it,
type: `/JOB CONTROL` and hit <kbd>ENTER</kbd> (good enough answer?!)

You might also like -> [www.tldp.org](http://www.tldp.org) -> Bash guides - for more elaborate text and examples.

You will though most likely have a problem launching "terminals" on your Mac - from the Ubuntu side - especially using Bash.